# "Many of which" and present continuous - which is more correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, syntactic-analysis

1. The ideas presented in this paper were extended in later works, many of which utilising the same model.
2. The ideas presented in this paper were extended in later works, many of which are utilising the same model.

Are both of these correct?

Comment: Example 1. Needs improvement. a) 'extended to' sounds more correct than 'extended in'. b) An auxiliary like 'are' is missing here. Example 2. Sounds just OK, but if I were, I would write, "The ideas presented in this paper were extended to the later works, many of which utilize the same model."

Comment: The *are* is NOT needed. There are no two separate sentences here. Read it as "The ideas ... later works, **with** many of **them** utilising the same model."

Comment: @Ram Pillai: if the ideas were further developed or enhanced in later works, then 'extended in' is correct.'Extended to' suggests that the same ideas were also used in later works.